# Code running in OXYGEN correctly but not in altova

Tags: xslt

I've an XML document, on which i was running an XSLT.

when i run it in Oxygen, the output is fine, but when i do the same in Altova, it is catching wrong `when` and giving a buggy output. When i went into the XML engine, it showed it as `SAXON HE` and in Altova i think it used `XALAN`, I tried to import the `SAXON jar file` and tere the parameters expected are %1(XML input), %2(Output File) and %3(XSL), but here the problem is i'm running on an entire set of files from project window.

CAn you please let me know how i can fix this issue and use `Saxon` to run multiple files.

Thanks

Comment: Please show the XML input file, the XSLT stylesheet - and explain why the output is "buggy".

Comment: What version of XSLT are you using?

Comment: Hi @Rnet, i use XSLT2.0

Comment: But i think the deafult processor in Altova is Xalan

Comment: OK, you've got inconsistent output between two processors and you think one of them is wrong. And you want us to help. Didn't it occur to you that we might want to know what the stylesheet is doing and how the output differs? And that if you gave this information, it would be easier for us to help you?

Answer (score 0):

Xalan does not support XSLT2.0. Saxon implements XSLT2.0. The arguments for saxon should be

```
-xsl:<xsl file> -s:<input xml> -o:<output file>
```

More here: http://www.saxonica.com/documentation9.5/using-xsl/commandline.html